# How to show if charger is plugged in/out on an Activity?

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

I am a newbie in android. I want to change a text of textview in an activity if a charger is plugged in or out. For that i have registered a receiver in manifest with intents `android.intent.action.ACTION_POWER_CONNECTED` `android.intent.action.ACTION_POWER_DISCONNECTED`

Following is the code for receiver:

```
public class PowerConnectionReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    if(intent.getAction() == Intent.ACTION_POWER_CONNECTED) {
        //Handle power connected
        Log.e("Charger State","power connected");
        Toast.makeText(context, "Charger PluggedIn", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } else if(intent.getAction() == Intent.ACTION_POWER_DISCONNECTED){
        //Handle power disconnected
        Log.e("Charger State","power disconnected");
        Toast.makeText(context, "Charger PluggedOut", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

   }
}
```

This is working perfectly but i want to show it on an activity when charger is plugged or unplugged. Please help me to acheive the task.

Thanks~

Comment: have  u write PowerConnectionReceiver  in manifest

Comment: yes i have written it and its working as i can see the toast message when charger is plugged in or out. The only thing is that i want to display the message on an activity say MainActivity.

Comment: do you want to show the connected status on textview in an activity??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many ways to pass data from Broadcast Receiver to the Activity

The best way is to use a Bus

```
compile 'org.greenrobot:eventbus:3.0.0'

//Some Class
public class MessageEvent {
   public final String message;

public MessageEvent(String message) {
    this.message = message;
   }
}

//In Activity
@Override
  public void onStart() {
  super.onStart();
  EventBus.getDefault().register(this);
}

@Override
 public void onStop() {
 EventBus.getDefault().unregister(this);
 super.onStop();
}

//From Broadcast Receiver
//Add this in the Connected and Disconnected methods 
EventBus.getDefault().post(new MessageEvent("Hello everyone!"));
```

Comment: You must have a broadcast receiver anyway, so why is it "the best way"?

Comment: Thanks a ton @VeereshCharantimath its working perfectly but you missed mentioning one thing here is about Preparing subscribers otherwise your answer helped me...

Comment: "The best way"... too much opinion here. I think its totally useless to use an external lib for something this simple. Why don't just use the LocalBroadcastManager?

Answer (score 0):

just write the code you used in you activity like this

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity{

 TextView mTextView;
 @Override
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    mTextView =(TextView) findViewById(R.id.text);

}

 public class PowerConnectionReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    if(intent.getAction() == Intent.ACTION_POWER_CONNECTED) {
        //Handle power connected
        Log.e("Charger State","power connected");
        mTextView.setText("Charger PluggedIn");
        Toast.makeText(context, "Charger PluggedIn", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } else if(intent.getAction() == Intent.ACTION_POWER_DISCONNECTED){
        //Handle power disconnected
        Log.e("Charger State","power disconnected");
        mTextView.setText("Charger PluggedOut");
        Toast.makeText(context, "Charger PluggedOut", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }else{
      mTextView.setText("");
     }

   }
}
```